# vba filter dates for all last quarter, and the last day into the quarter before that

Tags: excel, vba

The below snipped captures transaction dates for the last quarter, which is almost perfect, but i need to modify to capture 1 day beyond the last quarter...
Can anyone help me modify that?

Example, Last quarter data is Apr 01 to Jun 30, but I really need Mar 31 to Jun 30.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=11, _
Operator:=11, Criteria2:=0, SubField:=0
```